# Can Compression helps the performance of SSIS or SQL import export

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, compression

I have records in range of 20-30 millions in a table, I want to export these records to another server. using ssis or import export wizard of SQL, but speed is coming very low like 9000 records per 5 sec. I altered the maximum buffer size, and this is the best i can get, I feel like if data is compressed in source server. It should help transfer rate. Please comment ! any help is appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Any transformation that happens in SSIS? What is the bandwidth between the source and destination?

Comment: No transformation.. Is happening.. And Bandwidth cannot be changed!

Comment: How much is the bandwidth?

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using? Save your SSIS package from the Import/Export wizard and open up in Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT. In the Data Flow, look at the OLE DB Destination and put a screenshot of the properties

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less unknowable for us. Specifically, we don't know what the bottleneck is for your export, so compressing the data may or may not help. Now, my feeling is that your bottleneck is likely something other than how quickly SQL Server can get the data off of disk, but it might be. For your transfer, do a wait analysis from within SQL Server (perhaps with an extended event session) and see what it's waiting on.